# Purpose of Using a double pointer in Linked Lists

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, pass-by-reference, singly-linked-list

I have a few questions about this function which intends to delete all occurrence of a given integer in the list :

```c
void deleteAllOcc (node**headRef,int d)
{   
    node*temp;
    if (*headRef==NULL)
        return;
       
    while (*headRef)
    {
        if ((*headRef)->data==d)
        {
            temp=*headRef;
            *headRef=(*headRef)->next;
            free(temp);        
        }
        else
        {  
            headRef=&((*headRef)->next);
        }
    }
}
```

First why did we use `**headRef` instead of `*head` ?

Secondly, considering this :

```c
if ((*headRef)->data==d)
{
    temp=*headRef;
    *headRef=(*headRef)->next;
    free(temp);               
}
```

Don't we need to update the links ?

And third, considering this :

```c
else
{
    headRef=&((*headRef)->next);
}
```

Why we didnt do  *headRef=(*headRef)->next); here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters the function can be written simpler

```
void deleteAllOcc( node **headRef, int d )
{   
    while ( *headRef != NULL )
    {
        if ( ( *headRef )->data == d )
        { 
            node *temp = *headRef;
            *headRef = ( *headRef )->next;
            free( temp );
        }                    
        else
        {  
            headRef = &( *headRef )->next;
        }
    }
}
```

That is the first check for the equality of the passed by reference the pointer to the head node is redundant.

> First why did we use **headRef instead of *head?

It depends on how the function is defined. In the case of the function definition provided in your question the pointer to the head node is passed by reference that is through a pointer to the pointer head. In this case changing the pointed pointer head within the function you are changing the original pointer.

For example imagine that the list contains only one node and its data member `data`  is equal to the specified value of the argument `d`.

in main

```
node *head = malloc( sizeof( mode ) );
head->data = 1;
head->next = NULL;

deleteAllOcc( &head, 1 );
```

//...

and within the function `deleteAllOcc` you have

```
if((*headRef)->data==d)
{
    temp=*headRef;
    *headRef=(*headRef)->next;
    free(temp);
    
}
```

As `*headRef` yields the original pointer `head` in main then this statement

```
*headRef=(*headRef)->next;
```

changes the original pointer `head` in main bot a copy of the value of the pointer.

You could define the function in other way when the pointer to the head node is not passed by reference but passed by value. But in this case you need to return the possible new value for the pointer to the head node in main.

For example

```
node * deleteAllOcc( node *head, int d )
{
    while ( head != NULL && head->data == d )
    {
        node *temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free( temp );
    }

    if ( head != NULL )
    {
        for ( node *current = head; current->next != NULL; )
        {
            if ( current->next->data == d )
            {
                node *temp = current->next;
                current->next = current->next->next;
                free( temp );
            }
            else
            {
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
    }

    return head;
}
```

and in main the function should be called for example like

```
node *head = NULL;

//filling the list

head = deleteAllOcc( head, 1 );
```

As you can see the function definition when the pointer to the head node is passed by reference looks more simpler.

> how are we updating the links between the nodes after deleting a node

You have a pointer to the data member `next` of the current node. The pointed node by the data member `next` of the current node contains the value equal to the value of the parameter `d`. So the next node must be deleted. It ,means that the data member next of the current node shall point to the node after the deleted node. That is you need to write

```
*headRef = ( *headRef )->next;
```

where `headRef` at the current moment points to the data member `next` of the current
node.

```
|node1| next |  -> |node2| next | -> |node3| next |
         |            |
       headRef      node that must be deleted
```

So in the data member next pointed to by `headRef` you have to write the value of the data member next of the deleted node node2.

> why we didnt do *headRef=(*headRef)->next); here?

In this code snippet

```
else
{
   headRef=&((*headRef)->next);
}
```

you are reallocating the pointer `headRef` to point to the data member next of the next node. If you will write

```
*headRef = ( *headRef )->next;
```

then you will lose the node currently pointed to by the value stored in the expression `*headRef` that is in the currently pointed data member `next` will be changed rewriting the stored pointer.

Comment: Thanks alot. I think I made a big mistake by jumping directly into linked lists without fully understanding how pointers work. I can write a working function like a recursive version of the above function without really understanding how every step is done.

Answer (score 1):

> First why did we use `**headRef` instead of `*head`?

When you send the adress of a linked list to a function, you create a pointer on the first element of this list. It allows you to iterate on the list etc. But if you want to manipulate the complete list (or edit it), you have to create a pointer on this list, (that means a double pointer on this list by sending the adress of the linked list

> why we didnt do *headRef=(*headRef)->next); here?

Your method can work but I advise you to create a pointer to a temporary node **(node *tmp)** in order to assign the value to it and swap data with it. It's much more readable for everyone.

Comment: for my second question I meant how are we updating the links between the nodes after deleteing a node

Comment: I think your explanation "if you want to manipulate the complete list" is not fully clear. I suggest to add an explanation about call by value vs. emulating call by reference using a pointer.

Comment: Yeah you can do it by this way, or you can use a node *tmp to stock the actual data, and swap it in a easiest way (not a with a ***&*&*&*&**) ;)

Comment: @mrreaper72 If you want to clarify your question, please edit your question and add the clarification there.